# Hide the seekBar in PlayerNotificationManager media 3

Tags: android, android-media3

As mentioned in the title I would like to hide the seekbar from the notification when playing a live audio. Is there a way to customize the notification and achieve this behavior ?
Thank you for your help

Unless I missed it, I can't find the info in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/ui/PlayerNotificationManager

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the metadata to the media session try to set the `MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION` field to -1.